# Invoking Method on UI thread from within a Lock()

Tags: c#, multithreading, locking, invoke

I have two methods, `MethodA` & `MethodB`. `MethodB` has to run on the UI thread. I need them to run one after the other without allowing `MethodC` to run between them.

`MethodC` is called when a user clicks on a lovely little button.

What I did to ensure this is put a `Lock` around the code thus:

```
 lock (MyLock)
 {
   MethodA(param1, param2);

   MyDelegate del = new MyDelegate(MethodB);
   if (this.IsHandleCreated) this.Invoke(del);
 }
```

And for `MethodC`:

```
public void MethodC()
 lock (MyLock)
 {
   Do bewildering stuff.....
 }
```

Problem is I'm getting stuck. It looks like my code's going into a deadlock.

When I look at the threads I see that the code called by the button click is stuck at `lock (MyLock)` in `MethodC` and my other thread seems stuck at `this.Invoke(del)`.

I've read it's dangerous to invoke a method from within a `Lock` but since I'm the one who wrote the code there and this seems to happen even with just a `Thread.Sleep` I figure it's not the code that's getting me into trouble.

Why would the the Invoked method stop working?
Is it possibly waiting for the lock on `methodC` to be released before going back to the original lock it was invoked from?

Comment: Method C is waiting on a the lock which Method B has acquired and method C cant run b4 method B.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

So, imagine the following situation:

1. Your background thread starts running the code.  It grabs the lock and then starts running `MethodA`.
2. `MethodC` is called while `MethodA` is in the middle of its work.  `MethodA` waits for the lock to be free, blocking the UI thread until that happens.
3. The background thread finishes `MethodA` and goes to invoke `MethodB` on the UI thread.  `MethodB` can't run until all previous items in the message pump's queue have finished.
4. `MethodC` is at the top of the message pump's queue, waiting until `MethodB` finishes, and `MethodB` is in the queue waiting until `MethodC` finishes.  They are both waiting on each other, which is a deadlock.

So, how do you resolve this issue?  What you *really* need is some way of "waiting" on a lock without actually blocking the thread.  Fortunately (in .NET 4.5) this is easy to do thanks to the Task Parallel Library.  (I have waiting in quotes because we don't actually want to wait, we just want to execute `MethodC` as soon as the lock is freed *without* actually waiting/blocking the current thread.)

Instead of using an `object` for `MyLock` use:

```
private static SemaphoreSlim semaphore = new SemaphoreSlim(1, 1);
```

Now for `MethodC` you can do:

```
public async Task MethodC() //you can change the signature to return `void` if this is an event handler
{
    try
    {
        await semaphore.WaitAsync();
        //Do stuff
    }
    finally
    {
        semaphore.Release();
    }
}
```

The key here is that because we `await` a task that represents when the semaphore is actually free we aren't blocking the current thread, which will allow the other background task to marshal `MethodB` to the UI thread, finish the method, release the semaphore, and then let this method execute.

Your other code doesn't need to (but still can, if you want) use async waiting on the semaphore; blocking the background thread isn't nearly as much of a problem, so the only key change there is using the semaphore instead of `lock`:

```
public void Bar()
{
    try
    {
        semaphore.Wait();
        MethodA(param1, param2);

        MyDelegate del = new MyDelegate(MethodB);
        if (this.IsHandleCreated) this.Invoke(del);
    }
    finally
    {
        semaphore.Release();
    }
}
```

Comment: Precisely the situation! Mu question is why can't `MethodB` run if it's in the same Lock as A? Why is it trying to "re-enter"?

Comment: @E.T. It's not waiting on the lock at all.  It's just waiting to be scheduled by the windows message pump.  What it's waiting on is for `MethodC` to finish executing so that the UI thread can continue on executing other messages in the message pump, such as the message to run `MethodB`.  Also, see edit with solution added.

Comment: Thanks. Looking into it :)

Comment: Is there a solution for C# 4.0?

Comment: @gartenriese See [this series of blog posts](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/02/11/10266920.aspx) on creating various threading primitives for an async world.

Comment: They use FromResult, which is not available in C# 4.0.

Comment: @gartenriese It's trivial enough to write your own: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15562845/is-returning-an-empty-static-task-in-tpl-a-bad-practice/15571885#15571885

Comment: Yeah sorry, figured that out right after I asked. In your answer above, you are using async and await. What should I use instead?

Comment: @gartenriese `ContinueWith`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114852/discussion-between-gartenriese-and-servy).

Comment: @gartenriese: `await` can work perfectly fine in .Net 4.0.

Comment: @SLaks: I am trying to avoid any additional libraries.

Comment: @gartenriese: **Don't**.  Async is not simple; if you try to reinvent everything yourself, you'll be in for a world of pain.

Comment: @SLaks: It's not my decision, unfortunately. If it was, I'd be using .NET 4.6.1.

Answer (score -1):

Assuming your `MethodA` also contains something like:

```
lock(MyLock) {

}
```

You are absolutely correct, you've got a dead lock.  `MethodA` cannot obtain a lock on `MyLock` because it was already locked before the method was entered.

Comment: It would be fine if it was on the same thread - locks are re-entrant. What's problematic is if `MethodB` tries to obtain the lock...

Comment: `MethodA` doesn't lock anything. All locks are quoted. What I can't figure out is why `MethodB` is even trying to obtain the lock :-/

Answer (score -1):

You can rather try this:

```
Lock (MyLock)
 {
   MethodA(param1, param2);

   MyDelegate del = new MyDelegate(MethodB);
   MyDelegate del2 = new MyDelegate(MethodC);
   MyDelegate del3 = del+del2
   if (this.IsHandleCreated) this.Invoke(del3);
 }
```

Comment: But `MethodC` isn't always run right after `MethodB`.  Sometimes it's never run, sometimes it's run before, or twice, or before and after.  They're independent operations, they just can't run at the same time since they both require a shared resource of some sort.

Answer (score -1):

You confused a hell out of people using lock. This task has nothing to do with multi-threading per se.

Simple usability solution is what you need - disable your lovely little button until you are ready to run MethodC.

Comment: Thanks for that but this whole thing is called up at least once a second. And yeah, that's what got me confused too...

Comment: in that case you need to queue the user interactions and call MethodC if there is something in the queue. anyway it seems you need to explain logic in more details (it still feels like you are going in a wrong direction altogether)

Comment: OK I think Servy gave you right solution (if you know for sure that your A and B will run before C then you need a semaphore). but bear in mind you can lose control easily if a bug or unexpected situation will not call one of the methods and your code will hung forever... I will always opt for more manageable code (cant say more because there is not enough information on what you actually need to achieve calling these methods)